# Node readline parses and attempts to post individual lines to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, readline, fs

I'm trying to use node.js to process a .sql file for a MySQL database, but my code appears to be parsing each line of the .sql individually resulting in errors stating that there is an error in my syntax at Line 1: repeatedly.

I've tried to use the StringDecoder, but had no luck, as well as chunk.toString. Where am I going wrong? I would think this is a very simple scenario. Is there a better approach to have node execute a .sql script?

```
var mysql = require ('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306',
    database: 'test',
    user: 'test',
    password: 'test'
});

mysqlConnection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('database/builddb.sql'),
    terminal: true
});

rl.on('line', function(chunk){
    mysqlConnection.query(chunk.toString('ascii'), function(err, sets, fields){
        if(err) console.log(err);
    });
});

rl.on('close', function(){
    console.log("finished");
    mysqlConnection.end();
});
```

When I execute that as is, my connection is successful, but I receive errors such as:

```
computer:code username$ node builddb.js
finished
Connected!
{ [Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty]
  code: 'ER_EMPTY_QUERY',
  errno: 1065,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
{ [Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty]
  code: 'ER_EMPTY_QUERY',
  errno: 1065,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
{ [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '' at line 1]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
{ [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'event_id VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,' at line 1]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
{ [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'event_type VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,' at line 1]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
```

Edit: The SQL is very straight forward, just creating tables and inserting data. The script executes in MySQL Workbench just fine, but fails if I try to invoke it via the command line as well as via the Node program.

Snippet:

```
create database if not exists testdb;
use testdb;

/** drop tables if they exist **/
drop table if exists alerts;
drop table if exists checkpoint;
drop table if exists docs;

/** create tables **/
CREATE TABLE alerts (
    event_id VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    event_type VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    subscriber_id VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    file_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    message_details VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    notification_status VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PENDING' 
        CHECK (notification_status IN ('PENDING', 'SENT', 'EXCEPTION')),
    created_by VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'BATCH',
    created_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_id, event_type));

CREATE TABLE checkpoint (
    file_name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    processing_status VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PENDING'
    CHECK (processing_status IN ('PENDING', 'IN_PROCESS', 'COMPLETED', 'EXCEPTION')),
    created_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    last_modified_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (file_name));

CREATE TABLE docs (
    event_type VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    msg_id VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    doc_id VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (doc_id));
```

When executing via the command line, it returns this:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<filepath removed>/database/builddb.sql' at line 1
```

Comment: please paste your file with sql

Comment: Updated @ŁukaszSzewczak